# Authentication between React frontend and Node backend

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I think I'm having an issue passing a session from my Node backend to my React frontend, but I'm in kind of an I don't know what I don't know situation. Can anyone help?

Here's the issue:

I've got this route on the backend..

```
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
res.status(200).json({ user: req.user });
});
```

which spits out userdata JSON upon a successful Steam Passport authentication. I can verify this works when I check the account page generated by EJS views.

On the React server, I have a root page with a link to Steam auth. It successfully goes to Steam, then redirects back to the root page.

When I try to do a JSON fetch to '/account' from the root React page, the response is no longer JSON, but is HTML from the backend's '/account' template, but I need JSON of course.

I think it's not recognizing me as authenticated, because I get the same HTML response when doing a GET request using Chrome's Advanced REST client extension.
I should also note that I'm proxying the API server via Create React App's proxy feature.

UPDATE:  Problem solved.

`fetch('https://example.com:1234/users', {
  credentials: 'include'
})`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue may be due to the order of `app.get` calls, or the configuration of your node server – likely the EJS templates.

I would look for where you're doing something like `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` and where you're doing `app.get('/account'...`.

You'll want to do the `app.get('/account'..` *before* you do `app.set('view engine...`

If you actually hit the `/account` route you should get either a `401` or the JSON response, not HTML (EJS).

Comment: Turns out `req.isAuthenticated()` is returning false inside of this function I'm calling on the route:

`function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/');
}`

The response is HTML from being routed to root from this function.

If I tell ensureAuthenticated to return just next(), it'll at least spit out some JSON on a test route.

Not sure where to go from here.